# Return a list of record with Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List<Customer>Customer`, the Customer has as fields : Id, FirstName, LastName

I have a `List<Records>Records`, the Records has as fields : CustomerId, RecordId

I have a `List<Record> Record`, the Record has as fields : Id, FieldA, FieldB

I'd like to get back all the the Record depending of the `List<Customer>` means all the record with the Customer present in the Customer list

Do you have an idea ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this join will work:

```
from c in Customers
join r1 in Records on c.Id equals r1.CustomerId
join r2 in Record on r1.RecordId equals r2.Id
select r2
```

but I also think that the "Records" might be better named CustomerRecordLink or similar

Answer (score 0):

A Simple one would be using joins?

```
List<Record> result =
    (from c in Customer
    from rs in Records
    from r in Record
    where
    rs.CustomerId == c.id
    && r.id == rs.RecordId
    select r).Distinct().ToList();
```